# Bootstrap grid system - text goes on the next row when device width is smaller

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have the following structure of my page:

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <div class="picture">
          <div class="row" style="margin-left:0px !important;margin-right:0px !important;padding-bottom:10px;">
            <div class="col-md-1">
              <img src="url" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
              Some name <br/>
              Some email
            </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
     <div class="col-md-3">
       some text here
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My issue is that when device width is smaller, name and email goes on the next row but not in the same row where image is. How to fix that? It should be responsive. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every column at a mobile breakpoint will have a width of 100%, which means your .col-md-* classes will all have a width of 100% at smaller sizes. This is a common expectation for responsive grid systems.

To get the image and inputs on the same line, you will have to add another class that overrides the widths set by the bootstrap col classes. Bootstrap has specific classes to target different breakpoints that you can use. See: https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-1 col-xs-6">
  <img src="url" />
</div>
<div class="col-md-11 col-xs-6">
  Some name <br/>
  Some email
</div>
```

This should do the trick.